# VK API make POST with image attached at meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to send to a VK API image file with POST request. However, I can't find any information about how to do this on Meteor or Node js.

Can you help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour]. **Do you have any attempt to show?**

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have any idea what the vk image api is but I would start by looking at using the http api built in to meteor. It's pretty much just a wrapper for the node api.

https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html

Comment: Thank you. Yes - I try with it also. Solved with vkapi-node